# Can we limit the number of tests running in parallel with testtools.ConcurrentStreamTestSuite

Tags: python

I am converting from `unittest` to `testtools` to run my Python tests in parallel.

I would like to know if there is a way to limit the number of Tests that are running concurrently when using `testtools.ConcurrentStreamTestSuite`?  I will soon have hundreds of tests and will need to limit the execution to ~10 max at a time.  The remaining ones would be queued up and wait to be executed when a thread frees up.

If so, could you please share some code snippet that shows how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've cleaned-up the logic and here is a new version of that function (that works much better):

```
def split_suite_into_chunks(num_threads, suite):
    # Compute num_threads such that the number of threads does not exceed the value passed to the function
    # Keep num_threads to a reasonable number of threads
    if num_threads < 0: num_threads = 1
    if num_threads > 8: num_threads = 8
    num_tests = suite.countTestCases()
    s = []
    s_tmp = unittest.TestSuite()
    n = round(num_tests / num_threads)
    for case in suite:
        if n <= 0 and s_tmp.countTestCases() > 0:
            s.append([s_tmp, None])
            num_threads -= 1
            num_tests -= s_tmp.countTestCases()
            s_tmp = unittest.TestSuite()
            n = round(num_tests / num_threads)
        s_tmp.addTest(case)
        n -= 1
    if s_tmp.countTestCases() > 0:
        if s_tmp.countTestCases() > 0: s.append([s_tmp, None])
        num_tests -= s_tmp.countTestCases()
    if num_tests != 0: print("Error: num_tests should be 0 but is %s!" % num_tests)
    return s
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  All it takes, is to split up the tests and organize them into suites a certain way.
Here is some sample code (that needs some clean-up, but that does the job):

```
""" Splits a Test Suite so that no more than 'n' threads will execute the tests """
def split_suite_into_chunks(n, suite):
    # Keep n to a reasonable number of threads
    if n < 0:
        n = 1
    if n > 8:
        n = 8
    # Compute n such that the number of threads does not exceed the value passed to the function
    n = math.ceil(suite.countTestCases() / n)
    s = []
    i = 0
    s_tmp = unittest.TestSuite()
    for case in suite:
        if i < n:
            s_tmp.addTest(case)
            i += 1
        if i == n:
            s.append([s_tmp, None])
            i = 0
            s_tmp = unittest.TestSuite()
    if (i > 0):
        s.append([s_tmp, None])
    return s

def add_test_case_to_suite(suite, tc_name):
    # Creates a Test Suite with each Test Case added n times
    n = 1
    for i in range(0, n):
        suite.addTest(tc_name)

def get_suite():
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    add_test_case_to_suite(suite, My_login_test('tc_login'))
    add_test_case_to_suite(suite, My_login_test('tc_logout'))
    return suite

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # This is what sets the number of threads
    num_threads = 4
    suite = get_suite()
    concurrent_suite = testtools.ConcurrentStreamTestSuite(lambda: (split_suite_into_chunks(num_threads, suite)))
    result.startTestRun()
    concurrent_suite.run(result)
    result.stopTestRun()
```

`num_threads` in `__main__` is what sets the number of threads to use.  Interestingly, I realized that even if I set the number of threads to more than 8 (say 10), I never manage to run more than 8 threads at a time.  Not necessarily an issue (more of an observation) since it doesn't help me performance wise to have that many threads anyway.